# Difference between app home page and custom home page - Lightning

Tags: lightning, app-builder

I am following the trailhead Lightning App Builder module. Based on the content i have a doubt in the difference between app home page and custom home page.

Please help in explaining the difference.

Answer (score 4):

**App Home Page** is the default landing tab for when you switch to an app in Lightning.

**Custom Home Page** is when you want to override the Home tab in Lightning with your custom Lightning component.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [help doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_types.htm&language=es_2&type=0) that explains the different page types. Basically, the difference is:

- Home page is the 'Home' tab in Lightning, which you can customize in
  app builder.
- App (Home) Page are standalone pages that can be exposed as a
  independent tabs in the menu

A few differences are that there are different set of components exposed for each, app pages can have global actions added to them, app pages are built on responsive templates that can also be activated for Salesforce1, activation/assignment is done differently etc.